# Execution time for successful search Binary Search algorithm

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, algorithm, binary-search

I have implemented Binary Search Algorithm using Node.js. I am recording the time taken by the algorithm to search for a number in a random generated array. I am able to output the time taken by the algorithm for an ***unsuccessful search***.

But I am not able to figure out how to measure the time taken by the algorithm to ***successfully search*** a number in an array.

Here is my code -

```
function binarySearch(A,K)
{
   var l = 0; // min
   var r = A.length - 1; //max
   var n = A.length;
   var time = process.hrtime();

   while(l <= r)
   {
       var m = Math.floor((l + r)/2);

       if(K == A[m])
       {
           return m;
       }
       else if(K < A[m])
       {
           r = m - 1;
       }
       else
       {
           l = m + 1;
       }
   }
   time = process.hrtime(time);
   console.log('%d',time[1]/1000000);
   return -1;
}

var randomlyGenerateArray = function(size)
{
   var array = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxArrayValue);
       array.push(temp);
   }
   return array;
}

var sortNumber = function(a, b)
{
   return a - b;
}

var program = function()
{
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10000; i += 10)
    {
       var randomArray = randomlyGenerateArray(i);
       var sort = randomArray.sort(sortNumber);
       var randomKey = 100;
       var result = binarySearch(sort, randomKey);
       if(result < 0)
       {
           console.log("Element not found");
       }
       else
       {
           console.log('Element found in position ',result);
       }
    }
}

var maxArrayValue = 1000;

program();
```

I am using `var time = process.hrtime();` to start the timer at the beginning of the algorithm and using `time = process.hrtime(time);` to end the timer and output it in the console.

How can I measure the time taken by the algorithm to ***successfully search*** a number in an array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just copy those same two lines that are before the `return -1` to before the other `return` in the function.

Comment: @Pointy Thank You :) It works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your timer before calling the binary search function and end it after the call .. regardless of whether the search is successful or not, you will get the time ..

```
var time = process.hrtime();
var result = binarySearch(sort, randomKey);
time = process.hrtime(time);
......
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes total sense :)